# delete trigger to delete row in another table in another database sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, delete-row

I have a database schema called `Fulcrum` that has a table called `Orders` with PK on `OrderNO, OrderDate, TenantID`

I have a bridge database schema called `XFer` where I also have a table called `Orders` with the same field names but no keys on `OrderNO, OrderDate, TenantID`

I need to create a trigger behind the `Orders` in `Xfer` that deletes the matching row in `Fulcrum.dbo.Orders` when I delete the row in `XFer.dbo.Orders`

thank you

Comment: And do you have a question?

Comment: And what database is this?

Comment: What database system are you using? are both DBs on same server?

Comment: I need to create a trigger behind the Orders in Xfer that deletes the matching row in Fulcrum.dbo.Orders when i delete the row in XFer.dbo.orders

Comment: Yes, but what [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, Sybase and IBM DB2.??????

Comment: My apologies I assumed that The SQL Tag indicated Microsoft SQL server - I am new to this forum and therefore am bound to make a few errors and assumptions that are incorrect  I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 both databases are on the same server - table names and field names are identical I no longer am allowed to do events begind VB code - I have to use triggers (mgmt) and it is all very new to me  But I am a quick study and will never re-ask the same question here :)

Comment: Are all three columns required to match or only the orderno for a "match" to be made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering you are  using `Microsoft SQL Server` syntax to create such trigger is :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [XFer].[dbo].[OrderDeleted]
ON [Xfer].[dbo].[Orders]
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN

   DELETE FROM [Fulcrum].[dbo].[Orders] WHERE [Fulcrum].[dbo].[Orders].[OrderNO] IN (SELECT [XFer].[dbo].[Orders].[OrderNO] FROM DELETED)  

END
```

Obviously the syntax might not be perfect, but this is close to what you need.

Comment: If there are 3 fields that make up the uniqueness of identifying which record to delete can I use the following syntax:

Comment: Yes you can just change `where` clause accordingly.

Comment: If there are 3 fields that make up the uniqueness of identifying which record to delete can how can I identify all 3 fields - do I just identify them in he Select part or do I need to say "Where field1, field2, field3 IN (Select Field1,Field2,Field3 From deleted)

Comment: no you have to do like `where [Fulcrum].[dbo].[Orders].[OrderNO] in (SELECT [XFer].[dbo].[Orders].[OrderNO] FROM DELETED) and [Fulcrum].[dbo].[Orders].[OrderDate] in (SELECT [XFer].[dbo].[Orders].[OrderDate] FROM DELETED)` like wise..

Comment: I got a multipart error so I removed the references by Database and dbo.tablename but kept the filedname in the select part and it worked   Thank you soo much

Comment: @axsprog Great..Please update in answer what you corrected/modified

Comment: not sure how to do that but here is the correction        where [Fulcrum].[dbo].[Orders].[OrderNO] in (SELECT OrderNO FROM DELETED) and [Fulcrum].[dbo].[Orders].[OrderDate] in (SELECT OrderDate FROM DELETED)

Comment: I followed your answer @amog, can you please tell me how can i store the result in deleted? Should i have to create custom variable to store it as temporary before deletion from database table?