# SQL how to delete row using ON UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create two different SQL tables, which are related to each other. I have code that may leave behind ghost records (public code, cannot modify it myself). For example in the following situation

- Create record A (which has UID)
- Create record B which references record A (using the UID)
- Data stored elsewhere which was used to create record A is removed, but it does not remove the record A (this is the part i cannot modify, and it's not possible to run checks for the data due to its sheer size)
- Record A and B are still stored in the database, even though they should be removed
- New data is inserted into A's place using "REPLACE INTO..." at some point
- B is no longer referencing to A as A's data has been updated, including the A's UID
- B should NOT reference A, as it's outdated. B should be deleted

One method I'd like to use for doing this is the following table creation where foo is the UID:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS B (
  foo VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  bar VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  baz BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (foo, bar),
  FOREIGN KEY (foo) REFERENCES A(foo) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE DELETE,
  FOREIGN KEY (bar) REFERENCES C(bar) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The problem is, `ON UPDATE DELETE` does not exist as a statement.

One solution *could* be to just delete all B records before updating A, but is it possible at all to do so without running new delete statements and queries in the code?

Example:

Before:

A:

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| 121212 | someotherkey |

B:

| foo | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 121212 | ababab | 1 |
| 121212 | cdcdcd | 1 |

After updating A and inserting new relevant B data with `REPLACE INTO...` and `INSERT INTO B...`:

A:

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| 232323 | someotherkey |

B:

| foo | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 232323 | efefef | 1 |

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30740293/4892466

Comment: @Troy Turley the link you posted is for sqlserver not mysql -and won't work in mysql

Comment: Is this a periodic full load or partial load? And how is - 'A's data has been updated, including the A's UID' a replacement - more detail please together with sample data expected outcome and a's table definition (as text)

Comment: BTW replace is not an UPDATE it's either an insert or a delete and insert...

Comment: Since `REPLACE` deletes the old record, `ON DELETE CASCADE` should handle it. However, it will also delete the child row even if the `REPLACE` doesn't change the UID.

Comment: Usually if the parent record's UID is changed, you want to copy that to the child row, so that they still maintain the same relationship. Why do you want to delete it?

Comment: @Barmar I want to delete it as the data stored in B is related to the deleted data.I tested a bit with the ON DELETE CASCADE but it seems it only updates/deletes and inserts a new row to A, but it does not touch anything in table B. Even if the foreign key "foo" refers to a missing value in table A, it seems to be somehow allowing the missing value to exist in the database even with the foreign key constraint. (Edit) Just to be clear i created a new table with the exact same SQL as in this post, except i replaced ON UPDATE DELETE with ON UPDATE SET NULL

Comment: Also no, the data should not be deleted from B if the UID is not changed. This far it hasn't deleted it when doing some testing and running the replace statement

Comment: Are you sure A is being updated with `REPLACE`, not `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Comment: When I do `REPLACE INTO A` it deletes the record from `B` because of `ON DELETE CASCADE`. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d43e06/2

Comment: Yes, It's using REPLACE. I've dropped the tables and regenerated them, and the code I currently have does not use INSERT anywhere, as all of the queries are using REPLACE. I'm using WAMPServer MySQL 5.7.23, I guess it could have something to do with it. I'll have to test this a bit more later and I'll update if anything changes from the previous results